# Creating user for SQL Server database and accessing through C#.net application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created the users for SQL Server database. It got created just fine.

My problem is when I am accessing through application by executing the following code it does not switch to that user which I am specify as

```
exec as user='myuser'
ALTER USER myuser WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=maindb
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'myuser'
```

and I have run the query as

```
DbCommand command = ds.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "exec as user='myuser'";
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

from C# code

Waiting for your valuable responses and comments

Comment: where's your connectionstring? You could use SqlCommand class too instead of DbCommand

Comment: connecting string is  DbConnection ds = ""; the value get from web.config file

Comment: why don't you connect to the database as myuser ?

Comment: are you opening the connection? is it in a try-catch block?

Comment: @all i am just switching the db to different users in database

Comment: @FlorisPrijt s but no error coming

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is expected. the connection string contains the credentials required to connect to the server. and typically there is a single connection string between the application and database to optimize resources and take advantage of connection pooling etc.

different users may have different rights in the system, but that can be handled by authorization, not connection strings.

Comment: while creating users what command should i give to users for grant all permissions to access

Comment: you wouldn't. there would be a single account used to communicate between the application and the database. (at most 2, one for users and another for system admins). user's and their credentials/access/operations can be managed by another source. whether it's active directory, a set tables in RDBMS, hard coded config settings, document database, etc. one example of this is the asp.net membership provider for web applications.

Comment: i should clarify that managing the users is independent of the connection string and database operations. you can manage what actions the user is authorized to make, but this is not done at the database level, it's done within the application.

Answer (score 0):

[EXECUTE AS Clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx)

> The user or login name specified in EXECUTE AS clause must exist as a
>   principal in sys.database_principals or sys.server_principals,
>   respectively, or else the create or alter module operation fails.
>   Additionally, the user that creates or alters the module must have
>   IMPERSONATE permissions on the principal.

Do you satisfy those conditions?